# What is difference between button and a href?

Tags: django

when I use below,

```
 <button class="px-2 py-1 rounded bg-red-500 text-white">{{cta}}</button>
```

it works. but when I try url version, like:

```
<a href="{% url 'moneylogs:create' pk %} " >
    <div class="px-2 py-1 rounded bg-red-500 text-white">{{cta}}</div>
</a>
```

error occure, i guess it is because pk is invalid.

> Reverse for 'create' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['moneylogs/create/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

i tried pk=moneylog.pk but it also doesn't work.

my moneylog view is

```
class moneylog_create(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.CreateMoneylogForm
    template_name = "moneylogs/create.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        moneylog = form.save()
        moneybook = moneybook_models.Moneybook.objects.get(
            pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
        form.instance.moneybook = moneybook
        moneylog.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return redirect(reverse("moneybooks:detail", kwargs={'pk': moneybook.pk}))
```

and moneylog urls is like:

```
app_name = "moneylogs"

urlpatterns = [
    path("create/<int:pk>/", views.moneylog_create.as_view(), name="create"),
    path("update/<int:pk>/", views.moneylog_update.as_view(), name="update"),
    path("<int:moneybook.pk>/delete/<int:moneylog.pk>",
         views.moneylog_delete, name="delete"),
]
```

what is difference between button and a href? and why it doesn't work? how can i edit to a href version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable pk that you are parsing in is not giving back anything hence the

> arguments '('',)' not found.

you should instead try kwargs.pk

However if you are trying access the pk from within the createView you won't have access to the pk as the object hasn't been created yet to have a pk. The pk will only be available on the detail view and similar views.

The difference between href and button is that href is used for links and will normally take the user to another page and can be styled as a button, whereas a button is normally used to activate javascript on the page.